# How to set read/write permissions in Apache on a Windows computer

Tags: php, apache, security

I am building a web page with Apache2.2, PHP5.2.2 on a Windows XP computer in a localhost configuration. I'm developing app/pages/submitProcessor.php to validate photo uploads from users. It validates file existance, size, mime type, drops unwanted characters, assigns a new file name, and uses move_uploaded_file() to store the file in app/uploads. I read in [PHP - Question about uploading & uploaded image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339161/php-question-about-uploading-uploaded-image-file) that this photo storage file should be write only from app/pages/submitProcessor.php and it would be nice if it were read only from code within app/pages.

I've read a lot of info, and being pretty new to this, I still don't understand how to set read/write permissions in Windows XP in something resembling my configuration. I'm completely confused by 777, 775, 755, php.ini vs httpd.config and linux vs Windows.  I'm also not comfortable with command line stuff, and would prefer to edit the appropriate file, if that is possible. How do I configure Apache so any file in app/uploads will not be executable, will write only from app/pages/submitProcessor.php, and read from app/pages/display or others in app/pages . . . or at least I'd like to get close to that. Not executable in the app/upload directory is pretty important to me.

Comment: chmod (those values 777, 775 etc) is a unix system.. it seems that there is an program that simulates this on windows called CHMOD-Win, but I don't know if that is what you need..

Comment: @mishu thanks for the chmod clue.  I did some Googling and eventually found the equivalent for Windows. Its built into directory properties.

Comment: ok, I am glad.. just as a curiosity.. are you talking about ACL?

Comment: This might help: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XEKAb.jpg

Comment: While searching, I saw something called CACLS, but it looked like overkill and too complex (for me).  I found that you just right click on the directory/folder name in Explorer (the Windows file manager) and you get a dialog box with various access and use choices for that directory.

Comment: For me the issue was related to `<Directory>` directives. See more hints on this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, access to directories/folders is set by right clicking the directory, and reading through the selections provided by the various tabs to set access and specific uses of the directory.  Its not as fine-grained as CHMOD, but it was good enough for my purposes at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Apache as a Service (the default setup for stand-alone & WAMP Apache installations), then that Apache Service is running under Windows' `LocalSystem` account.

This Windows account already has full read and write ('777') permissions on most local paths.

So when you read instructions to `chmod 777` this, `chmod 755` that, etc, ... you can ignore those parts of the instructions. Apache already can read-from and writeout-to those directories (unless it's a UNC path of a networked drive).

[Setting File Permissions with chmod on Windows for Apache and PHP](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/setting-file-permissions-with-chmod-on-windows-for-apache-and-php)

*I'm not 100% positive if that was the account on Windows XP (it is on Vista and up), but the behavior was the same.*