# Zend Framework 3 Migration

Tags: php, zend-framework3

In Zf3 Project i have added Doctrine and migration module and also configure doctrine and migration configuration.

now i create migration through following command

[image]

anyone help me what's problem?

Answer (score 0):

the data directory in your project root, either does not exist or doesn't have the correct permissions.

Comment: data directory exists and i think in windows have not permissions issue right?

Comment: if you have git bash you can check them the easy way with chmod, otherwise you can follow the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9981560/3784145

Comment: i have given both way permission but still same error.

Comment: is `Migrations` also an existing folder?